# Why are my AT commands inconsistent?

Tags: pi-3b+, serial-console, gsm

Devices:

RPi3B+, USB to TTL CH340, SIM800C GSM module

Here are the connection between the USB to TTL and GSM module respectively

5V-VCC, TxD-RxD, RxD-TxD, GND-GND

Then I attach this USB to TTL to one of the USB ports of the RPi3B+

Whenever I connect to this serial using putty, every first time I enter "AT" I get an "ERROR" then all subsequent "AT" will return "OK"

Comment: Could you share the complete command with us?

Comment: Ah, you have some rubbish not flushed first.  If you are using python, flush first.